# Python - how to store lines of numerical values?

Tags: python

I have a file with many lines each having over 20 numerical values, e.g.:

```
123 1 18 180776 4303656 1605 16468 0 51429 24230 0 0 0 4 8 0 8710 14705 1836 1 4 95
0 24538 0 187860 4264028 449 4711 0 2537 2537 0 0 5 0 0 0 6138 12880 1590 1 22 76
...
```

I'd like to:

1. read one line
2. save it in some python data type (what would be the best ?)
3. do some operations on each number taken from the above line, e.g.:

   - check if it is not above sth (and save the result)
   - check if it is not belowe sth (and save the result)
   - count its length (number of digits) (and save the result)
   - compare it to the previous number from the same column
     -

So after a one line (with numbers) I should have:

1. store each number
2. store additional attributes for each number

Each number is compared to previous one from the same column, store the result but then I can forget the previous line.

What data type would be the best to store above data ?

Comment: "sth"?  What is "sth"?   Also, please flag your homework as [homework].

Comment: sth = abbrevation for "something", usually.  Although all numbers are above something.

Comment: "abbrevation for "something"?  Why can't @przemol simply use English?

Comment: Sth is English. Why not complain about his use of 'e.g.' which isn't even English? Or if you think it's a bad or lazy question, say that instead.

Comment: It is off topic but http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/e.g.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say which data type would be best without knowing what you're gonna do with the aggregated information. However, a simple solution would be to use a list for each line, containing 2-tuples with the actual number and a dictionary with attributes:

```
line = [(1, {'even': False, 'foo': 'bar'}), ..., (2332, {'even': True, 'foo': 'baz'}), ...]
```

Here's how to get this list starting from a line of text:

```
line = "4 0 2837 9323 ..."
line = [(int(n), dict()) for n in line.split()]
```

Then iterate the list and set attributes:

```
for n, attributes in line:
    ...
    attributes['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Comment: What is a function of dict() ? To have some space for additional attributes ?

Comment: @przemol: Yes. You said you want to *"store additional attributes for each number"*. That's what the dictionaries are meant for here. Of course there plenty other ways of storing meta data about numbers - it depends on the meta data and how you intend to use it subsequently.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you would use a `list` for this

When you read a line into a variable, say `row`

```
row.split()
```

will give you a `list` but each element will be a string, and you need numbers. You can get a list of numbers (looks like they are all integers) using a list comprehension like this

```
[int(x) for x in row.split()]
```

you can also use a list comprehension to compare with `sth`

This filters just the items that are < sth

```
[int(x) for x in row.split() if int(x)<sth]
```

This returns a list of `bool` where `True` means that the corresponding item is < `sth`

```
[int(x)<sth for x in row.split()]
```

Comment: How could I compare some value to the previous value from the same column ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard data types should be fine for most purposes: i.e. `list` or `tuple`.  Use `list` if you will be altering the values in-place.

You should be able to do something like this (untested code):

```
all_the_lines = []
with open("filename.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
        # do something with the data if you want
        all_the_lines.append(data)
```

After this, all_the_lines will hold a `list` of `list`s with the raw data (converted to integers).  You need to figure out how you will hold the other information you want to save: for example, pointers to all elements which were above a certain number.  You can calculate all this during the loop above, or afterward.

If you want to perform heavy-duty mathematical calculations on the numbers (it sounds like you don't), consider using `array`s from the `numpy` package instead.

Comment: It's better to just iterate over `f` instead of calling `readlines()`. `readlines()` reads the whole file into memory at once

Comment: oops, I was thinking readlines() returned a lazy iterator. edited.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/)

- [How to load an array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)
- [How to test array values](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html#array-contents)